# What penalties do shields have?

Tags: combat, rogue-trader, shield

Shield description says "Attacks made with a shield suffer a -20 penalty"
Shields also have "defensive" quality, which increases +15 to parry but attacks made by such weapons suffer -10 penalty.

Do the penalties stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ongoing debate, and one that each GM must decide.

According to rules as written **yes**, they stack. According to rules as intended they do not...

Comment: What's RAW and RaI?

Also, shields are the ONLY weapons with the "defensive" quality, am I right? That makes the penalties even weirder. If shields are not the only "defensive" weapons I'd say the penalties stack.

Comment: RAW = Rules as written, RAI = Rules as intended.

Comment: If wearing armor, I would prefer to be slashed 3 times with a sword across the face rather than being hit one time [with a shield](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkhpqAGdZPc).